# Setting up permissions for a Samba share

Tags: windows, samba, debian-wheezy

I have Samba running on my home NAS (just a bare bones computer with an external HDD attached) in order to transfer files to/from a Windows machine. It's mostly working, I can browse the shares I have set up however I cannot write to them.

My hard drive is mounted on `/media/HDD1`. The relevant parts of my Samba config are below:

```
security = user

[Media]
   comment = Media Storage
   path = /media/HDD1
   create mask = 0775
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes

[Files]
   comment = File Storage
   path = /media/HDD1
   create mask = 0775
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
```

When Samba is running, I can get to the shares from Windows by typing `\\nas` into Windows Explorer. However when I try to create a file/directory, or try to transfer one I get this error dialog:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvQH5.png]

Obviously it's something to do with user permissions, however I don't know what. If I comment `security = user` in the config I get the same error. From what I know having `read only` set to `no` should enable me to read/write as I please.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Whitey, your question is about home-use equipment which is considered on topic on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanting to allowing everyone with full read/write permissions. Then make sure to set your config to:

browseable = yes

guest ok = no

create mask = 0777

Also, make sure that once you do that, you give the samba service user account access to those directories you specified. By running: chown and chmod on those directories. Once you get this to work then you can start reducing the permissions to 775 and specify user accounts.

Comment: s2000lover, please do not add signatures to your posts.